# AWS cloudformation recordset creation failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I am trying to deploy an AWS cloudformation template with the following section

```
  APIDns:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSet'
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: myzoneid
      HostedZoneName: myhost.com
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !Join [ '', [ !Ref RestApi, '.execute-api.',!Ref 'AWS::Region','.amazonaws.com/',!Ref 'Stage'] ]
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false
      Type: A
      Name: api.myhost.com
```

I've have real string values instead of myzoneid and myhost

However creation of the recordset always fails with

```
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::Route53::RecordSet   APIDns     Property HostedZoneId cannot be empty.
```

Any clues on what is causing the failure? Cloudformation spec is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html and I suspect that AliasTarget might have some error. I'm trying to create an alias to another API gateway v2 API (ie type AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api)

Comment: Try to use quotes around the myzoneid value eg 'myzoneid'

Comment: This is confusing because HostedZoneId is a valid value in the RecordSet, and also under the AliasTarget. The error is complaining about AliasTarget.HostedZoneId being empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to specify both the HostedZoneName AND HostedZoneId.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html:

"Specify either HostedZoneName or HostedZoneId, but not both. If you have multiple hosted zones with the same domain name, you must specify the hosted zone using HostedZoneId."

Comment: this was one error.I also ended up adding AliasTarget.HostedZoneId to a regionalhostedzoneid for my usecase.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else trying to create an Alias record to a CloudFront and not making it through, you'll need to have a specific hard-coded value for `AliasTarget.HostedZoneId` as mentioned in the documentations [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget.html#aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-properties)
[image]

So, effectively, here's how your CloudFormation will look like:

```
  CloudFront:
  ....
  ....

  CloudFrontDnsRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: CHANGE_THIS
      Name: example.com
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
        HostedZoneId: "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2" # this is hard-coded value
        DNSName: !GetAtt Cloudfront.DomainName
```